# How can I change the bootstrap's well color?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-color

Well I've been trying to change bootstrap's well color, but it doesn't work, I've tried setting an image as background (the well's) and it worked, but that's not what I need. This is my HTML code:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>
Default.aspx
 </title>
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.11.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<link href="Styles/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="Styles/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />   
<link href="Styles/Default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> 
<script src="Scripts/bootstrap.js" type="text/javascript"></script>    
<script src="Scripts/Default.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="well well-lg"><h1 class="">TIDE File Generation</h1></div>
<div id="mainNavigator">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
      <li><a href="/TideFileGeneration.aspx">Validate file</a></li>
      <li><a href="/ImportCatalogs.aspx">Catalogs</a></li>
      <li><a href="/InvoiceHistory.aspx">View History</a></li>
      <li><a href="/Reports.aspx">Reports</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
 </body>
 </html>
```

And this is my CSS code:

```
.well{
background-color: rgb(22, 105, 173);
}
```

Is in the file Default.css

Thank you and regards.

Comment: And this isn't working? http://jsfiddle.net/sVQsg/

Comment: No, I mean, I can change everything but the color. I think there's something wrong on my syntax or maybe that's not where the color should be changed.

Comment: I got it guys: 
    <link href="Styles/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" /> Shouldn't be there. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm confused, but I'm glad you found something that helped.  Just in case you are testing in an old version of IE there is a background-color bug to keep an eye out for: http://css-tricks.com/ie-background-rgb-bug/

Comment: Thanks. I never heard about that, but I did what Micallef said (before he said it) and that's how I found out something was wrong. Thanks @JasonSperske

Comment: possible duplicate of [twitter bootstrap - well background color](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22915469/twitter-bootstrap-well-background-color)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That should work.

Try and inspect the element in Chrome to determine if some other css is overwriting the background-color. By default .well already contains a background-color - make sure you are replacing this.

Answer (score 50):

Bootstrap 3 :

Set the background property and not the background-color.

```
.well {
    background: rgb(22, 105, 173);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for this! Anyone happen to know what the default hex color for the well class is?

Comment: background-color : #f5f5f5

Comment: @MattO'Brien Otherwise, there is a `rgb()` color picker online [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_colorpicker.asp).

Comment: I found [this page](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Colors/Color_picker_tool) that helped me choose the color I want.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use !important in your default CSS to override the well background color:

```
.well{
background-color: cyan !important;
}
```

That worked for me.

Answer (score -4):

You can just add a style within the div where you declared your well.

Your code:

```
<div class="well well-lg"><h1 class=""> TIDE File Generation</h1></div>
```

Suggested code:

```
<div class="well well-lg" style="background-color: (color of choice);">
    <h1 class=""> TIDE File Generation</h1>
</div>`
```

Comment: While this will "fix" an issue, this defeats the purpose of CSS (Cascading Style Sheets). Not only this, but his problem is with CSS syntax, and not "div targetting"