# twitter bootstrap - well background color

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to change the background color and opacity of a bootstrap well. I've got the following CSS:

```
.well {
    opacity: 0.9; /* opacity [0-1] */
    -moz-opacity: 0.9; /* opacity [0-1] */
    -webkit-opacity: 0.9; /* opacity [0-1] */
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The opacity is working, but the background-color does not seem to change. Any ideas?

Edit [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m0atz/6F9L4/) added in case you want a play-a-round

Comment: write background:blue instead of background-color;

Comment: wow - that simple!! thanks it worked.

Comment: So what's the difference between 'background-colour' and 'background'?

Comment: background will have priority over other more specific background properties like background-color, background-image, because it can set them all in one declaration. it will overwrite them all just with one line. in the above topic we had div.well with predefined "background-color:#f5f5f5" (in bootstrap.css) and background-image (in bootstrap.theme.css). 
So we overwrote it all with just background:blue;

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Or you could write it in one line of css as rgba.

```
.well{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 255, 0.9);
}
```